# Send Button Overlaps with Emoji Button (React Chat Components)

Tags: getstream-io

[image: chat components on iPhone X]

I am using the Stream Chat UI Components for React.js. Works great on larger screens, but I on mobile the emoji button overlaps with the send button. When attempting to send a message, the emoji menu appears making it impossible to send chat message. Please help!

Comment: What version of the library are you on?